# What pattern comes next?

Tags: pattern, visual

Below are four patterns in a sequence, 1 through 4.
Which of the patterns A through H would be number 5 in that sequence?

[image]

Comment: D hurts my eyes so I hope it’s not that :P

Comment: Still working on proof, but I think it's probably that squiggly one, next to the one with the zigzags...

Comment: @Alconja Oh, yes, that one. I know the one you mean. ;)

Comment: Really? I'm certain it's the one with the circle.

Comment: I'm going to need to go to the eye doctor after this.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

The answer is

> that squiggly one, next to the one with the zigzag. I mean **pattern F**.

Because

> it continues all the following patterns:
>  [image][image]ING
>  [image][image]
>  [image][image]NGE

(As an apology for adding to the eyesore with the differently scaled squares, I removed the [epilepsy inducing earlier solution/punishment/joke thingy](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1zoC4.gif).)

Comment: Can you add the solution panel to your answer so it gets clearer how it fits in?

Comment: @ Tweakimp, great idea. Done.

Comment: As a bonus question - what is the meaning of the eyestrain-inducing option D?

Comment: @Bass  think it's fruit robot

Comment: @rubio, If it weren’t for the top horizontal line, I’d say it’s a signature. Since it’s there, I have to go with ”burrito”. (I’m sure you wouldn’t intentionally confuse us by using different shapes for P and R. Who could be so cruel..)

Comment: Do your thoughts here change if I mention that an I has three segments and not just one?

Comment: @Rubio well, no, since Fruit Robot is such a pleasant concept. But エ see your point.